# Can not connect to HDInsight emulator

Tags: .net, azure, azure-hdinsight

I have installed HDInsight emulator and now I am trying to connect to it using HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio.

It successfully connects to WebHDFS and HiveServer2, but it fails to connect to WebHCat (error detail: The requested task failed to complete in the allotted time)

From the logs for templeton I can see that there are some problems with connecting to resource manager (it retrying to connect to server all the time)

All hadoop services have status "running" and for http://localhost:50111/templeton/v1/status I get response: {"status":"ok","version":"v1"}

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: I have exact the same problem, add following config to yarn-site.xml has no help: `<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name> <value>127.0.0.1:8032</value>`

Comment: I think the reason is I haven't install hdinsight (MSSingleNodeInstaller.msi), I only maually installed hdp(hdp-2.1.3.0.winpkg.msi).